# Use of quotes in GNU grep regular expressions

Tags: bash, shell, grep, quoting

I could see that certain patterns in the GNU Grep can be enclosed within brackets and certain others need not be. For example, matching the beginning of a word works only if it is enclosed within quotes.

```
user@host:~/Desktop$ grep -E '\<H' test
Hello World
user@host:~/Desktop$ grep -E \<H test
```

[test contains the string Hello World]

But matching end and beginning of file works without dollar:

```
user@host:~/Desktop$ egrep d$ test
Hello World
```

Why is it so? And what is the rule?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quotes are expanded by the shell, they determine what `grep` sees.

With `grep -E '\<H'`, the characters between the single quotes are passed literally, so grep sees the regex `\<H` containing the beginning-of-word anchor `\<`.

With `grep -E \<H`, the backslash character removes the special meaning of `<` in the shell, and `grep` sees the regex `<H`. You would see matches for a line like `<Hello>`.

With `grep -E <H`, the `<` character would have its special meaning in the shell as a redirection character, so `grep` would receive the contents of the file called `H` on its standard input.

With `grep 'd$'` or `grep d\$`, the dollar sign is quoted so it reaches `grep`: the regex is `d$`, matching a `d` at the end of a line.

With `grep d$ test`, the `$` sign is not followed by a valid variable name or by valid punctuation (`${`, `$(`). When that happens, the shell passes the `$` sign literally, so `grep` again sees the regex `d$`. `$` is only expanded when it is followed by a valid variable name (even if the variable is undefined — what matters is that a name follows, as in `$PATH` or `$fioejsfoeij` or single-character variables such as `$-` or `$$`), or in the constructs `${…}`, `$(…)`, `$((…))` (also `$[…]` in bash and zsh, and more constructs in zsh).

The complete rules for shell expansion are far too complex to describe in a post or a dozen. In practice it's enough to remember the usual cases:

- `\` (backslash) quotes the next character unless it's a newline, and the backslash is always stripped;
- `'…'` (single quotes) quotes every character except `'` itself;
- `"…"` (double quotes) quote every character except `` "$\` ``, and `\` inside double quotes causes the following character to be interpreted literally and is only stripped if the next character was special.

Comment: Also note that e.g. `"This and $that"` expands the shell variable `that` (yes, it is implicit in the answer, but it is a snare for unvary newbies...)

Answer (score 0):

The `\<` is first escaped by the shell and its value becomes the literal `<` character. So the regular expression passed to `grep` is the string `<H`, which doesn't have a special meaning.

And if you need a deep knowledge of that particular relation you should consult Gilles' answer.

Comment: Also can have some extra fun with `\\\<H`...