# Regular expression within single quotes- lose their value?

Tags: regular-expression, quoting

The book I am reading - Learning the Bash Shell by O'Reilly specifies some code as follows:

```
if [ -n "$(echo $1 | grep '^-[0-9][0-9]*$')" ]; then 

   howmany=$1

   shift
   ....
   ....
   etc
```

> This uses the `grep` search utility to test if `$1` matches the appropriate pattern. To do this we provide the regular expression `^-[0-9][0-9]*$` to grep, which is interpreted as "an initial dash followed by a digit, optionally followed by one or more digits." If a match is found then `grep` will return the match and the test will be true, otherwise `grep` will return nothing and processing will pass to the `elif` test.
>
> **Notice that we have enclosed the regular expression in single quotes to stop the shell from interpreting the $ and *, and pass them through to grep unmodified.**

Then, why doesn't the regular expression `'^-[0-9]'` lose it's meaning as in single quotes, usually everything within single quotes loses it's meaning.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66488/use-of-quotes-in-gnu-grep-regular-expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes tell the shell to keep the enclose characters as is, [without any interpretation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html#Single-Quotes). The quoted string is passed as-is to `grep`, without the quotes: when `grep` looks for its arguments, it sees

```
grep
```

and

```
^-[0-9][0-9]*$
```

and acts on that. (Read [How programs get run](https://lwn.net/Articles/630727/) if you're curious about argument construction in Linux.)

`bash` and `grep` are different. The way this command uses quotes ensures that `bash` doesn't process the string, but `grep` does.

Answer (score 3):

While others have answered your specific question, I'll add that

```
if [ -n "$(echo $1 | grep '^-[0-9][0-9]*$')" ]; then
```

Is a wrong way to check whether a string matches a regular expression for several reasons:

1. [You can't use `echo` for arbitrary data](/q/65803)
2. Leaving a parameter expansion unquoted like that `$1` above is the split+glob operator.
3. `grep` doesn't match the regex against its full input, but on every line of it's input. So it would return true on `foo\n-0\nbar` for instance.
4. A regexp can match with zero length, so it's wrong in the general case to check if `grep` produces some output (note that command substitution strips trailing newline characters). It's better use `grep -q` and rely on the exit status of `grep`, rather than that of `[`, and also avoid the command substitution.
5. Note that that `grep` command can be simplified to `grep -xE '-[0-9]+'`

`bash`, `ksh93` and `zsh` have a dedicated operator for (extended) regexp matching. To use it portably and reliably across all three (and bash-3.1), the syntax is:

```
re='^-[0-9]+$'
if [[ $1 =~ $re ]]; then
  echo matches
fi
```

`yash` and `zsh` also support:

```
if [ "$1" '=~' '^-[0-9]+$' ]; then
  echo matches
fi
```

The standard command to do string (basic) regex matching is `expr`:

```
if expr " $1" : ' -[0-9]\{1,\}$' > /dev/null; then
  echo matches
fi
```

Note that the `^` (but not `$`) is implicit in `expr`. We also use that leading space character to avoid problems with values of `$1` that happen to be `expr` operators.

Also note that if the regex contains `\(...\)`, it will affect the behaviour of `expr`.

All in all, it's better to use `awk` instead which is another standard/portable way to do it (note that `awk` uses extended regexps):

```
if STRING=$1 RE='^-[0-9]+$' awk '
  BEGIN{exit(ENVIRON["STRING"] !~ ENVIRON["RE"])}'; then
...
```

Or use a function:

```
re_match() {
  STRING=$1 RE=$2 awk '
    BEGIN{exit(ENVIRON["STRING"] !~ ENVIRON["RE"])}'
}

if re_match "$1" '^-[0-9]+$'
```

In this case, you can also achieve it with a standard `case` construct:

```
case $1 in
  ("" | *[!0-9-]* | [!-]* | - | ?*-*) ;;
  (*) echo match;;
esac
```

To use `grep`, you could use it with the `--null` option (where supported as that's not a standard option) to tell it to work on NUL delimited records instead of newline delimited records. Since in most shells, `$1` cannot contain NULs, that should be safe:

```
 if printf %s "$1" | grep --null -xq '-[0-9]+$'; then
   echo match
 fi
```

Comment: Stéphane, the extent of your knowledge is always astounding. This goes far beyond what was asked in the question, thank you for sharing !

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes prevent *globbing* (letting `bash` interpret wildcards like `*`) and variable expansion through the use of `$`. Basically you're saying to `bash` "take literally those characters and pass them to `grep`". When `grep` sees them, it is built to understand regular expression so *then* the regexp is interpretted inside `grep`.

Shorter version: single quoting arguments provides a mean to escape processing from your shell before the argument is passed to the command.

Answer (score -2):

It does lose its meaning. `grep` uses a nearly same regex patterns as bash.

Comment: But doesnt the book say it doesn't.  ^-[0-9][0-9]*$ to grep, which is interpreted as "an initial dash followed by a digit, optionally followed by one or more digits

Comment: commands in single quotes ('command') lose their meaning _in bash_, and passed without any interpreting.

Comment: Bash doesn't use regex patterns, it uses globbing patterns.

Comment: @IporSircer does that mean bash and grep are different?